# append to the typeahead list of suggestions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

hi i'm really struggling with this and not sure how to proceed as I haven't found anything ont his. Here's the plunkr example I'm working with: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekDQRs?p=preview).
I want to append something at the end of the results for example if I type S, I want to get the results and the last line should say "Look for S in other shops" :

```
Sauron
Bowser
Yoshi
Look for S in other shops
```

As you can see in my plunker, whatever I do in the template, ends up getting repeated.

Comment: Hi @Riz, does my answer solve your question? If it does, could you please mark it as accepted? If it doesn't, could you please explain me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your custom filter:

```
.filter('finalAppend', function(){
  return function(array, value){ 
    array.push({
    name: 'Look for ' + value + ' in other shops',
    type: 'good'
  }); 
    return array;
  }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
 typeahead="datum.name for datum in (data|filter:$viewValue|limitTo:8)|finalAppend:$viewValue" 
 typeahead-template-url='tpl.html'>
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Om2ZgHcynzz3ZY3T48oI?p=preview)

Comment: sorry again , I erased my answer. Initially I tried to comment , but your answer was deleted.

Comment: @Senthil no problem, what happened is that when I published my original answer I realized that I had forgotten to set the second parameter of the `$filter`, therefore I temporarily deleted it while I was updating it.

Comment: @Senthil sorry if I over-reacted, you couldn't know what I was doing, you didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: @Senthil thanks! you could give it a vote up though ;)

Comment: why not , its deserves :)

Comment: @Riz I'm glad that I was able to help you out!

Comment: @Josep Hi Josep, I've posted another question related to this, maybe you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708085/angular-typeahead-filter-use-html-tags thanks in advance.

Comment: @Riz For sure! I'm going to have a look at it later. Thanks!