# angular typeahead filter: use html tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using a filter with angular typeahead to append an extra item onto the typeahead suggestion list like so:

```
app.filter('finalAppend', function($sce){
  return function(array, value){ 
    array.push({
    name: $sce.trustAsHtml('Look for <b>' + value + '</b> in other shops'),
    type: 'good'
    }); 
    return array;
  }
});
```

I want to return html encoded string, but angular automatically sanitizes it. I tried using $sce as suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the plunkr: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekDQRs?p=preview)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in ui-bootstrap 0.7.0, there is a conflict between typehead highlight filter and your own finalAppend filter.

Just change your tpl.html to this :

```
<div ng-if="match.model.type!=null">
    <span  ng-bind-html="match.label"></span>
</div>
```

And load angular sanitize to prevent secure error automatically been thrown by angular.

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

inject ngSanitize into your app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
```

And it works. [Here is the plunker address.](http://plnkr.co/edit/7aXBkycxEFLH58kBC4Nv?p=preview)

However, if you still want to use the typeahead inner highlight filter, you can change you ui-bootstrap to this(Already change it in the demo):

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
```

Hope this can work. Enjoy it. : )